# Google cloud in browser ssh download dysfinctional

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am troubled with my in browser ssh download functionality of google cloud platform. It was working quite well until recently when I started to observe un expected behavour. Everytime I have attempted to download a file the progress bar shows as if something is downloading but after completing nothing is found in the downloads folder. I have tried to switch and log onto another os partition on my local machine. But still experience the same problem even when I changed browser program nothing seems working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the Cloud Shell to host machine ? Or any other GCP product, maybe Storage ? If it is from the Storage try to issue `$gsutil cp gs://[bucket_name]/[file] /[host]`.

Comment: The thing is that I would like to view a file from /var/log/daemon.log path of the gce instance vm for debugging the startup-script. But due to what I have described into my question that path is inaccessible for the moment

Answer (score 0):

Google experienced an issue around the same time you reported the error. It has since been marked as resolved.

Are you still experiencing the same issue?

If that  is the case, you can report it in the [Issue Trackers platform](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).